# EF Code First + lazy loading, projection does not work as expected

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, projection, eager-loading

I have something like this:

```
var tmp =_forumsDb.Threads
.Where(t => t.Id == variable)
.Select(t => new { Thread = t, Posts = t.Posts.Take(1) })
.Single();
```

Now, i expect `tmp.Thread.Posts.Count();` to be 1, but it takes all posts that i have in database. Is it possible to use projection that takes explicit amount of posts, do it in a single query without turning off lazy loading?

Edit:
I tried doing something like this, but it does not work either:

```
var tmp =_forumsDb.Threads
.Where(t => t.Id == variable)
.Select(t => new { Thread = t, Posts = t.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.DateCreated).Take(1) })
.Select(t => t.Thread)
.Single();
```

Comment: I think this is a legitm question and doesn't deservers the downvote.

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is simply: No. Why don't you want to turn off lazy loading? Do you want it for other navigation properties of the `Thread` entity?

Answer (score 2):

`tmp.Thread.Posts` is the navigation property for which lazy loading is configured. Since it isn't yet loaded, accessing it loads all the remaining posts.

`tmp.Posts` is not a navigation property. That's the one you should be able to access without triggering another query.

Comment: Yes, tmp.Posts is loaded correctly, and it is only single post. But I want it to project this tmp.Posts into tmp.Thread.Posts, how do i do it?

Comment: @ojek Lazy loading is either enabled for all navigation properties, or disabled for all navigation properties. There simply isn't any way to disable it for one specific property of one specific object.